# Error connecting http through URL in vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vagrant, virtualbox

I am not being able to get an answer to my http request through the url that I placed in the windows HOST file. However, if you order through the IP of the machine works perfectly.

The content of my HOST file:

```
172.0.0.10 sogets.dev
```

The content of my VagrantFile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.0.0.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "yii2.dev", "/var/www/yii2.dev"
end
```

The response to an http request via "sogest.dev" is "Connection Refused"

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues:

1. The allocated IP

`172.0.0.10` is not within IP range for Private Network, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Please make sure to set an IP within the allowed range for Private Network, otherwise your request is going to the real server and not against your VM.

2. the Host file

When you allocated a private IP to your VM, then you must use this IP in your host file.

Lets say you have following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.34.10"
```

Then you'll write in your host file

```
192.168.34.10 sogets.dev
```

Answer (score 0):

"It appears that Google wants to use .dev only for internal puposes. Under that assumption it seems to be safe to host a "fake" dev zone on your internal DNS server"
[Solution](https://superuser.com/a/919280)